# Wave Modifier Question

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics, windows

I'm using a wave modifier on a cylinder, but I notice the ends of the cylinder are moving up and down. I'm wanting the ends of the cylinder to be angled as they move instead of just just translating vertically. A demonstration is linked below. Any ideas on how to do that?

[image: movement example]

[image: my setup]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, the Wave modifier just moves vertices up and down but doesn't rotate anything because it just works on the single vertices translating them on the z axis depending on their X and Y position.

If you want to make a curved pipe in which the section rotates and not translates, I recommend you to use a curve modifier. You'll need a sinusoidal curve (look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/99888/30865) for that) and a curve modifier to apply on the cylinder.